# How to avoid duplicate values going into the mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable $Title and contains the following:

```
$Title = aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff
$Pubdate = aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff
$Link = aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff
```

and I insert it into the table with the column name Title. (Nice simple so far)

However, the variable updates every 1 hour and for example may turn into this.

```
$Title = cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh
$Pubdate = cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh
$Link = cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh
```

FYI: the values like "aa" of `$Title` are not the same value with "aa" of `$Pubdate` or of `$Link`, but are linked to each other 
I was wondering if there is a way to avoid duplicate values going into the table again, so that only 'gg' and 'hh' goes in.

I know you can do it easily if you specify one value, like this

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ytable (Title, Pubdate, Link) VALUES ('aa','aa');
```

but when it updates, I'm not sure what the next value will be so I need your help.

Comment: you can set title column as your primary key which wont allow to repeat the values present already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a `UNIQUE` constraint on your database. That way, whenever you try to insert a row with the same value, it will be rejected by the database.

Here is a sample query, which you may have to adapt:

```
ALTER TABLE foo MODIFY Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE;
```

This ensures that the database will protest when you attempt to insert a row without a unique `Title` value.